# Find the order of $2$ in the group of units of the ring of integers modulo $p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, ring-theory

Question: A prime $p$ is such that $1/p$ when represented in octal (base $8$) notation equals $0.003310033100331\ldots$. What is the order of $2$ in the group of units of the ring of integers modulo $p$?

We know there are $(p-1)$ elements in the set of units of $\mathbf Z_p$.
Thus cleary , $2^{p-1} = 1$.

Given $1/p = 0.003310033100331\ldots= 3 \times 8^{-3} + 3 \times 8^{-4} + 1 \times 8^{-5} + \cdots$

From this how I can find $p$?

If I take reciprocal I get p = 151. Then easily I can continue.

But without using calculator Is there any way?

Comment: Octal $331$ is decimal $217$, $8^5-1 = 32767$, so $p = 32767/217 = 4681/31 = 151$. You shouldn't need a calculator for that! To calculate the order of $2$, it is helpful to observe that $2^{15} \equiv 1 \bmod 32767$ so the order must divide $15$.

Comment: Got it .Thank you

Comment: How did you calculate
 the order of 2 is 15?